# Getting Zone error in angular project after removing hash from route

Tags: angular

Getting Zone error in angular project after removing hash from route
After moving has from "export const routing: `ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);`"[image: This is the error]

Comment: Not enter the image in `url`

Comment: Please formulate a question, and format the code for better readability :)